# Cakephp : Create a member account from an email confirmation only

Tags: cakephp

For a project I need to create a membership from a customer database with CakePHP.

Eg The client submits a registration form containing a single field email and receive a confirmation email containing a link to an edit page profile he must complete to create your account (username, password, etc. ).

I do not know how to start my controller and model.

Thank you for your help

cordially

Comment: Your answer does not help me, thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry it does not always help me, thank you. I'm just asking advice on how to build my application.

Comment: Why do it this way? Why not just let them register their username and password on the registration page. This extra step with the email serves no purpose.

Comment: For spcéficiques needs. It there's no extra step, the background processes is simply reversed (instead of validating email after registration, the user is done before). This allows me to check if the user requesting registration and good customer and not just a visitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit broad for here, but he's a brief outline of how you might start to go with this from your CustomersController:-

```
class CustomersController extends AppController {

    public function register() {

        // Drive your registration form from this action and on successful form
        // submission email user a unique registration token using CakeEmail
        // that links to the confirmation action.

    }

    public function confirm_email($registrationToken) {

        // Check user's registration token and confirm their account.

    }   

}
```

Basically users would start by going to example.com/customers/register and provide their email address. When you process the data and save it to your database generate a unique registration token (and store it with the customer's data in the database). Email the token as part of a link to the confirm_email action, e.g. example.com/customers/confirm_email/X2458FHJ, using [CakeEmail](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html). When the user goes to the link you'll want to check the registration token in your confirm_email action and proceed from there.

Comment: Hello Drmonkeyninja, thank you for your answer. I understand the logic, I'm starting to code my application and would return here. Thank you for your help. Cordially